NextJS redirect with cookies
I'm building an app using NextJS (app router system). I'm building the sign-up workflow, using NextAuth, and Resend. I'm using the newly available Resend provider from NextAuth.
Here is the workflow explained:

Sign-up form to get the user's email.
When submitted, I'm calling a server action which triggers the signIn() method from NextAuth.
This sends a custom email, with a validation code that I created. A verificationToken is automatically created in DB, using the NextAuth Adapter for Prisma.
The user clicks on the validation button inside the email to be redirected to my validation page where he can input the validation code he received (an 6 digits OTP).
When the form is submitted, it triggers a server action that checks if the code is correct and perform a redirect to the onboarding page.

My process works until the 5th step, where I'm being redirected to the onboarding page. I can see a session token created in my cookies, and I can also see that this line const session = await auth(); is storing my session object inside my root layout.tsx. Same for the console.log("Session in Navbar: ", session); inside my Navbar.tsx component.
However it seems that isLoggedIn is not evaluate to true inside my tsx component (Navbar), and I can see that the logs from terminal and the ones from the browser console are not the same (isLoggedin=true on server, and false on browser).
When I manually reload the onboarding page, using cmd+R, my Navbar is updating as I want.
my root layout.tsx
import "./globals.css";
import { auth } from "../../auth";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import { Poppins } from "next/font/google";
import { Navbar } from "@/components/Navbar";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import { Toaster } from "@/components/ui/toaster";

const fontHeading = Poppins({
    subsets: ["latin"],
    display: "swap",
    variable: "--font-heading",
    weight: ["100", "200", "300", "400", "500", "600", "700", "800", "900"],
});

const fontBody = Poppins({
    subsets: ["latin"],
    display: "swap",
    variable: "--font-body",
    weight: ["100", "200", "300", "400", "500", "600", "700", "800", "900"],
});

export default async function RootLayout({
    children,
}: Readonly<{
    children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
    const session = await auth();
    console.log("Session in Layout: ", session);

    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body
                className={cn(
                    "antialiased",
                    fontHeading.variable,
                    fontBody.variable
                )}
            >
                <SessionProvider session={session}>
                    <Navbar />
                    <section className="px-[5%]">{children}</section>
                </SessionProvider>
                <Toaster />
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}


my Navbar component
"use client";

import Link from "next/link";
import { Sheet, SheetTrigger, SheetContent } from "@/components/ui/sheet";
import { NavLink, Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import Logo from "./Logo";
import { Menu } from "lucide-react";
import { Separator } from "./ui/separator";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/react";

export function Navbar() {
    const { data: session, status, update } = useSession();

    const [isSheetOpen, setSheetOpen] = useState(false);
    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

    const handleCloseSheet = () => {
        setSheetOpen(false);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        if (status === "authenticated") {
            setIsLoggedIn(true);
            update();
        } else {
            setIsLoggedIn(false);
        }
    }, [status, session]);

    console.log("Session in Navbar: ", session);
    console.log("Current time is: ", new Date().toLocaleTimeString());

    return (
// I'm performing an if condition on the value of isLoggedIn to modify the UI of the Navbar here


I tried refresh the page using useRouter() hook inside my Navbar component.
I tried a window.location.reload() to simulate a CMD+R.
I tried using useEffect() inside the Navbar component.

